# 8bit number as input in android

Tags: java, android, blob

I want to use an EditText in my android app which enables users to enter 8 bit numbers into the column. Which need to be stored in the database and would retrieve the 8 bit number when asked to display?.I am unable to figure out how to do that. Help me with this.Thank you

Comment: Show us what you tried. As it stands, this question is too broad.

Comment: I assume you want an unsigned 8-bit number. Use an `int`. The type `byte` is signed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Octal is base-8 number system.
You can use numbers ranging from 0 - 7.

`int octal = 01` acts as an Octal number, the prefix 0 indicates octal.

You can make your `EditText` show only numeric keyboard and before saving it in the database check if the entry contains 8 or 9 display a message as "Not a decimal number" else save it in your database and while displaying append a 0 in the beginning and show it on your UI.